# Rails 4 Jquery datepicker doesn't show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

my jquery ui datepicker works fine when I directly open the link (http://localhost:3000/expenses/dateForm) after running the rails application. But when I give the link for the view ('/expenses/dateForm') on my home page 'Reports button' and open the link on clicking Reports button on home page, datepicker doesnt show up.

Below is the view 'dateForm' :

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'expenses', :action => 'dateFilter'}, :class =>"datepicker") do %>
<%= collection_select Category, :id, Category.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => "Please select category..." %>
<%= label_tag("Start Date") %> <br />
<%= text_field_tag(:start_date) %>
<%= label_tag("End Date") %> <br />
<%= text_field_tag(:end_date) %>
<%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is home.html.erb :

```
<section class="form-button-item"> 
  <%= link_to "Reports", '/expenses/dateForm', class: "btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary"%>
</section>
```

Below is my application.js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#start_date").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
$("#end_date").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});

});
```

Please suggest the fix for this issue.

Comment: Can you post application.html.erb first few lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rails 4 turbolinks added by default, and turbolink makes application faster requesting same resources/assets without recompiling on page load.

That means when you paste direct url into browser it reloads the whole page but If you click on link it won't be able to reload and assets are not going to reloaded. so dtepicker doesn't seems to initialize and it won't work.
For you replace this code :

```
<section class="form-button-item"> 
  <%= link_to "Reports", '/expenses/dateForm', class: "btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary", data: { no_turbolink: true }%>
</section>
```

You can disable turbolink also from your application :
http://blog.flightswithfriends.com/post/53943440505/how-to-disable-turbolinks-in-rails-4

For more detail about turbo link : https://github.com/rails/turbolinks